# Как ввести список с клавиатуры?

Tags: python

Есть задание:

1.Нужно ввести два списка с клавиатуры

2.Нужно перемножить.

Вот пример:
Нужно ввести такие списки с клавиатуры:

```
l1 = [a, 3, 4]
l2 = [d, c, 5]
```

И при умножении должно выйти это

```
l3 = [ad, ccc, 20]
```

Как перемножить их я разобрался но как ввести и числа и буквы с клавиатуры не знаю.

Comment: здесь не очень любят вопросы, автор которых не сделал даже простейших вещей, чтобы найти ответ на элементарный вопрос. Ввод с клавиатуры осуществляется функцией input().

Comment: Google -> `python input list` - самые первые ссылки, куча вариантов

Comment: там есть только ввод чисел или строк по отдельности

Comment: list2 = []
N = int(input('Введите размер первого списка с клавиатуры:'))
for x in range(N):
    x = input('Вводите данные:')
    try:  
        list1.append(int(x))
    except ValueError:
       list1.append(x) если кому то нужно то получился такой код

Comment: Это вам кажется, что по отдельности. На самом деле там везде про ввод строк. Даже там, где вы думаете, что это про ввод чисел.

Answer (score 1):

https://ideone.com/6rHepJ

```
a = input().split()
b = input().split()
c = [a[i]+b[i] for i in range(min(len(a), len(b)))]
print(c)
```

По поводу преобразования ответ [в соседнем вопросе](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1059479/178988), а тебе даже проверка на отрицательные числа не нужна.

Comment: Дак у него явно указанно, что `3` и `c` должно стать `ccc`. А у вас получается `3c`. =) Либо тс, сам не понял, что написал.

Comment: @And, это я не понял. Поэтому довабил ссылку на ответ, где сказано как скастить список. А про то, что делать с двумя списками он в вопросе написал, что уже умеет, так что нет смысла второй раз изобретать.

Comment: Ну ты-же,, должен понимать, что код может быть разный, и для его "Я умею", твой код может не подойти. Он нигде не показал, как он умеет и что он там делает,.

Comment: @And, ну сделав `[int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in input().split()]` он получит интересующие его списки, а дальше он умеет :)